# Automatically Update Age when ever the date of birth arrives in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to update age column without doing nothing.

Whenever the date of birth changes, it should automatically update the age column - is there is any solution?

This is for SQL Server 2008

Please help me

Comment: If you *have* the date of birth - then the `Age` really just becomes a **calculation** - so you could store it as a calculated column that is automagically updated each time the date of birth changes

Answer (score 2):

If you already *have* the date of birth in your table, then the `Age` really just becomes a **calculation**. You could store it as a calculated column that is automagically updated each time the date of birth changes - or you could just calculate it in a `SELECT` as needed.

The question is: what "precision" of age do you need? The `DATEDIFF` functions in SQL Server are a bit "rough" - the `DATEDIFF(YEAR, ....)` calculation e.g. only looks at the **year** of two dates - so

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, '20171231', '20180101')
```

will return **1** - even though these two dates - Dec 31, 2017 and Jan 1, 2018 - are only 1 day apart.

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employees
(
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1000, 11)
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    DateOfBirth DATE,
    AgeInYears AS DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, SYSDATETIME()),
    AgeInMonths AS DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateOfBirth, SYSDATETIME()),
    AgeInDays AS DATEDIFF(DAY, DateOfBirth, SYSDATETIME())
)
```

and then see which "age" (in days, months or years) is sufficiently accurate for your needs.

Comment: Mr. Marc I have written the insert query in stored procedure where the date of birth calculation is there. My question is how is automatically get updated Please brief it if i retrieve a record how it going to automatically update the column record ??

Comment: @Mohamedjamalbatcha: that's OK - for the moment when you actually *insert* (or update) the data - but one day later, it's not current and correct anymore.

Comment: let me explain clearly i have employees data in my database, if i insert the employee data it will automatically calculate the age that i written in stored procedure, but if the date of birth of an employee may be tomorrow if i retrieve the employee details will it automatically show the updated one